# Does saving the cookie or jwt token in the browser raise a security risk?

Tags: cookies, jwt, access-token

I have an admin screen, once I access it, it asks for login credentials, then after I login, I get a token that is saved under local storage (see screenshot below)

[image]

Noting that I am using edge browser in private mode, when I opem a new tab, I am directly directed to the admin screen without login (which seems normal since token is saved in browser), but the weird thing is that even when I open a new edge browser in private mode I still can see the token when I access the admin url.
Few questions here:

1. Is there a security issue here with saving the token on the browser side?
2. I tried to take the token and inject it in burp as a header but the request failed, I am missing something here ?( I tried also adding it as a cookie but didn't work, seems I am missing something here)
3. Is it normal that when opening a new edge browser in private mode it is still loading the token?

Comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#renew-the-session-id-after-any-privilege-level-change and https://www.acrossecurity.com/papers/session_fixation.pdf (5.1)

Comment: Saving the token on the browser? no problem. Trusting it without regard to the current session? Problem...

Comment: @schroeder you mean mapping the token to the session? so if the token is within same session screen can be accessed, if there is a mismatch, the screen wont be accessed, and will be redirected to login screen. That's your point ?

Comment: "even when I open a new edge browser in private mode" Did you remember to close all of your old private browsing windows before you tried that?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica oops, I just noticed there was still an edge browser running it was lost between the 100 opened tabs :D.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to want to enter your credentials before every request, some authentication information (token, session ID etc.), must be stored *somewhere* in the browser. There's no way around that.

Whether or not this particular implementation poses a security risk depends on multiple factors.

- If the token is randomly generated with a secure random number generator for each session, that's fine. Then it's essentially a classical session ID. However, if the token is constant across all sessions or predictable, an attacker can gain unrestricted access to the user account by either stealing or predicting the token.
- If the server only accepts the token for a specific duration, this is good. Otherwise, there's again the risk of an attacker abusing the token for unrestricted access.
- If there are no cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities on the target site, the token is safe from being stolen through JavaScript due to the same-origin policy. Otherwise, an attacker can read the token and use it however they want.

In general, Local Storage is not a great place to store secrets, because there downsides compared to cookies. First off, Local Storage does not expire. With cookies, it's possible to automatically clear the session ID when the browser is closed. (Note that the server still has to enforce a time limit independent from the client). A better option would be Session Storage. Secondly, JavaScript has unrestricted access to Local Storage. With cookies, it's possible to prevent this with the `HttpOnly` flag (how much this helps is debatable, though).

Comment: If opening a new tab (and using private mode) don't those start new sessions?

Comment: @schroeder: Is this a response to JosephSible-ReinstateMonica in the question comments above? Otherwise, I don't understand the context.

Comment: @Ja1024, but are you saying cookies is safer than token in local or session storage ?I thought a token is always more secure than a cookie.
To note that in my case its a JWT token and has a signature.

Comment: Is it a JWT Access Token or a short-term Refresh Token? Storing an Access Token in Local Storage would be extremely insecure, because it does not expire and is not stored encrypted. It's almost as bad as storing the plaintext password in the browser.

Comment: @Ja1024 it is an access token. But what do you rmsn bu i does not expire ? Each jwt token has a TTL

Comment: JWTs *can* have an `exp` claim for the expiration time, but this is optional, and on the client side, the token is kept in Local Storage indefinitely. In comparison, session cookies are immediately deleted when the browser session ends. JWTs also don't expire when the user logs out (unless the server keeps a blacklist of invalidated JWTs). It's definitely not true that JWTs are more secure than classical cookie-based session with server-side state. I'm not sure this is even a common claim. Usually, JWTs are used for performance reasons, not for security.

Comment: @Ja1024 you said "the token is kept in Local Storage indefinitely", if that is true, in my test cae, why when I close the browser, the token (which is JWT) dissapears from my browser and I have to re-login?
as for "session cookies are immediately deleted when the browser session ends" what do you mean by session ends? because cookies are also saved in the browser so that whenever you want to access a resource the cookie is sent in each request, so even if browser closed cookie is sent and it is valid, no?